# Running Ant exec task without "Result:" output

Tags: ant, exec

When the Ant exec task runs a command that completes with non-zero exit status, the exec task outputs the status, such as:

```
 [exec] Result: 1
```

This is printed without context, and so it is confusing to users.
It is printed even if the exec task is invoked with `outputproperty="someproperty" failonerror="false"`.
I use such an invocation for commands such as `grep`, where a non-zero output may be the desired, expected result.

Is there a way to suppress the "Result: " output, without making any other changes to the output of the Ant process?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following example which uses JavaScript to disable and restore logging.

### build.xml

```
<project name="ant-exec-intentional-fail" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <echo>Show that exec logs "Result: 1" by default...</echo>
        <exec executable="sh" failonerror="false">
            <arg value="-c"/>
            <arg value="exit 1"/>
        </exec>
        <echo>Disabling logging...</echo>
        <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
            var savedLoggers = project.getBuildListeners();
            for( var i = 0; i < savedLoggers.length; i++ ) {
                var logger = savedLoggers[i];
                project.removeBuildListener( logger );
            }
            project.addReference( "savedLoggers", savedLoggers );
        ]]></script>
        <exec executable="sh" failonerror="false" resultproperty="middle-sh-result">
            <arg value="-c"/>
            <arg value="exit 42"/>
        </exec>
        <!-- Restore logging. -->
        <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
            var savedLoggers = project.getReference( "savedLoggers" );
            for( var i = 0; i < savedLoggers.length; i++ ) {
                var logger = savedLoggers[i];
                project.addBuildListener( logger );
            }
        ]]></script>
        <echo>Verify logging works again...</echo>
        <exec executable="sh" failonerror="false">
            <arg value="-c"/>
            <arg value="exit 1"/>
        </exec>
        <echo>By the way, the middle exec returned: ${middle-sh-result}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

### Output

```
run:
 [echo] Show that exec logs "Result: 1" by default...
 [exec] Result: 1
 [echo] Disabling logging...
 [echo] Verify logging works again...
 [exec] Result: 1
 [echo] By the way, the middle exec returned: 42
```

Comment: Even if that works (I haven't tried), this is way too much code just to eliminate one line of slightly annoying logging output...

Answer (score 0):

Late answer - but perhaps it will help someone that stumbles across this question searching the internet and does not want to completely disable logging (like Chad Nouis proposed): If one starts the program in a separate shell, the exit code can be controlled.

Ignore/Overwrite with exit code 0:

```
<exec executable="sh">
  <arg value="-c" />
  <arg value="cmd-with-non-0-exit.sh || exit 0" />
</exec>
```

Store exit code <> 0 to property:

```
<exec executable="sh" outputproperty="cmdOutput">
  <arg value="-c" />
  <arg value="cmd-with-non-0-exit.sh || echo $?" />
</exec>
```

The exit code then can be parsed from `$cmdOutput`.